# Can not call `vim` within go code

Tags: command-line, go

I try to call `vim` within go program, which code similar to this:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        err := exec.Command("vim", "a.txt").Run()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
        os.Exit(0)
}
```

I ran `go run mycode.go` then got:

```
exit status 1
```

I have tried several ways to succeed this e.g. replace `Run()` by `Start()`, `Output()`, `...`, but it seems not work. Finally, What I try to do is I try to call `vim` and stop my current go program. I just want to see `vim` appear, that's all.

Comment: What happens when you put the absolute path to vim?

Comment: Just nothing changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for vim to render its interface, you need to attach the standard input/output streams to the process:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("vim", "a.txt")
        cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
        os.Exit(0)
}
```

Not attaching the streams is similar to running the following command from your shell:

```
vim < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: To be more precise, Vim, being a full-screen text editor expects at least its standard input and output streams to be connected to a device having capabilities of a terminal.  That is, if you'd run your program which spawns Vim with its stdin/strout redirected to `/dev/null` vim would seize to work in exactly the same way. So the key reason Vim failed to work is that it can only sensibly work on a terminal.

Comment: To make my comment complete, sometimes one might need to run a program wich expects to be connected to a terminal device in an unattended way (one example is running something asking for a password interactively, such as a stock OpenSSH client). For this, pseudo terminal subsystem might be used, via a package such as [`github.com/kr/pty`](https://github.com/kr/pty). JFTR, terminal emulators, like `xterm`, and terminal multiplexers such as `screen` and `tmux` use PTYs to run their client programs.